# Starting a bash background process on OS X

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, process

I’m using a modification of [Paul Biggar’s LaTeX build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240037/recommended-build-system-for-latex).

The core of this system is just a bash script that executes an infinite loop. The question is, how do I run this script?

At the moment I just run it by invoking it in the terminal:

```
$ ./build-it.sh report
```

However, there are two problems with this:

1. It clutters the terminal with irrelevant output. Redirecting the standard output/error streams to `/dev/null` doesn’t help. In fact, *every line* that is executed in the script is also written to the console. Is this even normal?
2. After some time (about 30 minutes, I’d say) the script terminates with an error (“Cputime limit exceeded”).

The first problem could probably be solved by using [`nohup`](https://superuser.com/questions/38549/starting-a-linux-process-in-the-background) and closing the terminal window. But this still leaves the second problem. I also feel that this isn’t a “clean” solution because I’d prefer to run the script normally in the background and prevent its standard output (and incidentally, *not* error messages).

Isn’t there a proper way to do this?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the script posted as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240037/recommended-build-system-for-latex/1394702#1394702), then you can **remove the `set -x`** which is for debugging.

If you redirect the `stderr` of the script, instead, it should suppress the debugging output, but it will also suppress any error messages.

**Edit:**

Also there's a `ulimit -t 10` line in that script. Removing that will probably help.

Comment: The `ulimit -t 10` *in* the script needs to stay – and it shouldn’t affect the script itself: otherwise, the script would stop after only 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ulimit -t unlimited
```

for setting cputime limit, and

```
man bash
```

for more options of `ulimit` bash built-in command

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn’t work either: I used `(ulimit -t unlimited; ./build-it.sh report)` but the script stops after a time all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `$ ./build-it.sh report & exit` which will solve the first issue.

As for the second, it may have more to do with the actual script.

Comment: Not sure I can follow – the cputime limit doesn’t have anything to do with the script, that’s the same for all scripts. What I’d like to do is switch off the cputime limit *for this specific script*.